# Comparing the Date Columns of Two Dataframes and Keeping the Rows with the same Dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, I would like to keep the rows in each dataframe containing the same dates as the other one:

```
df1
>  Date     Price  Volume
0  2002-01-04   100    200
1  2002-01-05   200    400
2  2002-01-06   300    600
3  2002-01-07   400    800
4  2002-01-08   500    1000
5  2002-01-09   600    1200
6  2002-01-10   700    1400
df2
>  Date     Price  Volume
0  2002-01-04   100    200
1  2002-01-05   200    400
2  2002-01-06   300    600
3  2002-01-07   400    800
4  2002-01-09   500    1000
5  2002-01-11   600    1200
6  2002-01-12   700    1400
7  2002-01-13   800    1600
```

Desired output:

```
df1
>  Date     Price  Volume
0  2002-01-04   100    200
1  2002-01-05   200    400
2  2002-01-06   300    600
3  2002-01-07   400    800
5  2002-01-09   600    1200
df2
>  Date     Price  Volume
0  2002-01-04   100    200
1  2002-01-05   200    400
2  2002-01-06   300    600
3  2002-01-07   400    800
4  2002-01-09   500    1000
```

Comment: Convert to DatetimeIndex and use the `intersection` method on indexes to get common dates. Use it to filter.

Comment: Thank you so much @Riley! I can mark your comment as a solution to my question if you would like to post it as an answer to my post. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Nah thats ok. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First make the date column as index and then do the following:

```
common_index = set(df1.index).intersection(df2.index)
df1 = df1.loc[common_index].copy()
df2 = df2.loc[common_index].copy()
```